# Using a method to set the image of a label in python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

i'm trying to set an image on a label with this method, the photo image package is limited in the image extensions it can use, for instance it will not read .jpg without first putting in through the `Image` class. i know this image can be put onto a label as i do it the same way elsewhere, the only difference is that this one is setting in a separate method as opposed to in the same block as the label that uses it.
this is the label i'm trying to create by calling this method.

```
Label(self.daysCanvas, height=5, width=5, bg=self.setColor(), image=self.setalert(),relief = RIDGE)
```

the error i keep getting is a `pyimage1 does not exist` error

i'm wondering if it's because i'm trying to set it in a method, or if there is another error

```
def setalert(self):
     print(self.accdis,self.arrdis,self.hrdis,self.metric)
     image = ''
     # acc alert checker if checked in expertGUI
     if self.accdis == 1 and self.metric == 'ACC':
         print('acc')
         temp = Image.open(self.accimg)
         temp = temp.resize((5, 5), Image.ANTIALIAS)
         image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)
     # arousal alert checker if checked in expertGUI
     elif self.arrdis == 1 and self.metric == 'EDA':
         print('eda')
         temp = Image.open(self.arrimg)
         temp = temp.resize((5, 5), Image.ANTIALIAS)
         image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)
     # heart rate alert checker if checked in expertGUI
     elif self.hrdis == 1 and self.metric == 'HR':
         print('hr')
         temp = Image.open(self.hrimg)
         temp = temp.resize((5, 5), Image.ANTIALIAS)
         image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp)
     return image
```

i'm using python 3.6 on windows and the pillow package for PIL

Comment: It's difficult to tell without an m.c.v.e but it may be a lifetime issue. Sometimes tkinter doesnt bump up the ref count of objects passed to it and so they can be garbage collected after they go out of scope. The solution usually is to attach the object to `self`.

Comment: i was using Tk instead of Toplevel. something about Tk makes images drop in a spawned process. so if one tk window creates another, and that one uses Tk instead of Toplevel. certain data can be messed up.

Comment: I have no idea as to the issue. If you can provide an [m.c.v.e.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will allow others the opportunity to reproduce your issue.

Comment: From my experience this error is normally brought up when the image is loaded before the main window has been created or (most likely) the image when loaded is 'forgotten'. I fix this by using classes and defining the image as an attribute ```self.```